# How Optimize ace editor replace function?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I have an electron app, where I'm using ace editor. As I said in a previous post, in my app I read files, check the content and i mark lines that can be translated. Everything works fine. When the users translate the texts, i save it in a database so, if the user open some file that was previously translated, I check the "translated" texts and replace these lines for the actual translation text. Everything works good. But, some files take too long to load.

This is the replacing segment code:

```
    insertTranslateLines:function(trasnlate,linea,idMarker,inline,item){

        // console.log($this.__time($this.start),"ak",linea);
        var currentLine = $this.obtLinea(linea);
        trasnlateStr = trasnlate.trasnlate;
        if(inline || $this.lineaEnComillas(currentLine)){
            trasnlateStr = trasnlate.trasnlate.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, ''); 

            if(!inline){
                var endReemplazo= currentLine.lastIndexOf("\"");
                var startLine   = currentLine.indexOf("\"")+1;
                var partEnd     = startLine + trasnlateStr.length;
            }
            else{
                var texto       = currentLine.match($this.expresiones.cadenaTraducir2);
                var startLine   = currentLine.indexOf(texto[item])+1;//se suma uno para eliminar la comilla
                var partEnd     = startLine + trasnlateStr.length;
                var endReemplazo= startLine + texto[item].length-2;//se restan las comillas
                // texto = currentLine.split($this.expresiones.cadenaTraducirSplit);

            }               

            highLightRange  = $this.setRange(linea,startLine,linea,partEnd);
            replaceRange    = $this.setRange(linea,startLine,linea,endReemplazo);
            // $this.editorActual.session.replace(replaceRange,trasnlateStr);
        }else{
             replaceRange = $this.setRange(linea,0,linea,currentLine.length);
             highLightRange = $this.setRange(linea,0,linea,trasnlateStr.length);    
        }
        token = $this.editorActual.session.bgTokenizer.getTokens(linea,0);

        // $this.editorActual.session.replace(replaceRange,trasnlateStr);
        if(typeof highLightRange!='undefined'){
            $this
                .registerTrasnlate(idMarker,highLightRange);
            if(token[0].type!='comment')
            {
                $this.setMarker(idMarker,highLightRange);
            }


            return highLightRange;
        }else return false;



}
```

the code below, is a method from my javascript object. $this is an alias for (this (object scope)). This method gets the line where there is a text that has been translated and replaced from the orignal text. As I said before, so far everything works fine but there process takes a lot of time. Testing it, **I have detected the next line is the problem: **

```
$this.editorActual.session.replace(replaceRange,trasnlateStr);
```

As you see, this line was at the first segment of code but "commented". If i comment this line, the file loads in 391 milliseconds. but if i discomment the line, the file loads between 45000 and 60000 milliseconds (can be more, the time varies by the file size). The files have between 1000 and 1800 lines.

"$this.editorActual" is my ace editor instance. I only found the "session.replace" as method for replacing texts, and logically without this line, my app does not work. So, i would like to know if There is another fastest way to replace the lines ?wan to know. There is another fastest way to replace the lines ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace is slow because it has to keep history in undo manager and create events. You can replace translations on the string before calling setValue or craeting the session

Comment: Hi, tanks for aswer. The think is, I used the "hightlighting" as a tool to identify the lines. You said that i need to modify the text widthout use the ace editor? or exist a way to use it without the "session" ?

Comment: how many highlight ranges do you have and how do you update them when text is modified? the issue may be related to adding many anchors, in which case more info is needed

Comment: It depends, but can be a lot of texts. I think that the answer is the correct way and, I'm modifiying my app logic and replacing all text before insert it into ace editor. This way is fastest than how i did. Thanks